# Input to Jmeter SOAP/XML-RPC Request via multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: java, jmeter, apache-tika

**My Problem:** 
I have all my test data inside an excel + multiple sheets. I am trying to read the excel data & store it as a User Defined variable in Jmeter. I plan to use this:

- As a variable in a Request XML I send via SOAP/XML-RPC Request
- As a assert variable of the Response XML that I receive.

**What have I done so far:**
I am using a similar example as in [Jmeter : upload excel, hard coded values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047720/jmeter-upload-excel-hard-coded-values)

- The first sheet has A1 and B1 cells of testfile.xlsx file as "foo" and "bar"
- I have downloaded tika-app-1.9.jar & added in the /lib folder of Jmeter(v2.13)
- Added Beanshell PreProcessor & in the Script section added:

  ```
  import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.WebServiceSampler;
  import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;

  FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/excel/testfile.xlsx"));
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
  Cell a1 = row.getCell(0);
  String a1Value = a1.getStringCellValue();
  Cell a2 = row.getCell(1);
  String a2Value = a2.getStringCellValue();

  excelFile.close();

  sampler.addArgument("foo",a1Value);
  sampler.addArgument("bar",a2Value);
  ```

When I use the variable ${foo} in my SOAP/XML-RPC Request, the value does not get replaced with the value, but stays as ${foo}.

Any idea on what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In case of [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) sampler you cannot use `sampler.addArgument()`.

If you store `a1Value` and `a2Value` into JMeter variables "foo" and "bar" as:

```
vars.put("foo", a1Value);
vars.put("bar", a2Value);
```

Options are:

**Beanshell Way**

```
sampler.setXmlData("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<maintag>\n" +
        "    <sometag foo=\"" + vars.get("foo") + "\"/>\n" +
        "    <someothertag bar=\"" + vars.get("bar") + "\"/>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</maintag>");
```

**GUI way**

Inject variables into SOAP/XML-RPC Sampler code directly like

[image: SOAP Sampler]

In regards do multiple sheets this line:

- `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);` will return the very first sheet
- `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);` will return 2nd sheet
- `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt("MySheet");` will return sheet named "MySheet"

See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide for more details on how to work with external binary files in JMeter.